# Parameter name is missing, While executing Function via code

Tags: vb.net, function, postgresql, stored-procedures

am trying to execute the following code

```
 Dim transaction As PgSqlTransaction
    Dim command As New PgSqlCommand
    Dim paramLastNo As PgSqlParameter = command.Parameters.Add("funcUpdategtab03", PgSqlType.Int)
    command.Connection = Myconnstr
    Myconnstr.Open()
    command.Transaction = transaction
    transaction = command.Connection.BeginTransaction()
    Try
        command.CommandText = _
        "select funcUpdategtab03(" & SORD & "," & gintAcYrId & "," & gintBranchId & ");"
        command.ExecuteScalar()
        updateGtab03 = paramLastNo.Value
        transaction.Commit()

        Return updateGtab03
    Catch ex As Exception
        transaction.Rollback()
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Information, "RStari9 - updateGtab03")
    Catch ex As Exception
        transaction.Rollback()
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Information, "RStari9 - updateGtab03")
    Finally
        Myconnstr.Close()
    End Try
```

and the function that i have created is

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION funcupdategtab03(ivrid integer, iacyrid integer, ibranchid integer)
  RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$
declare id_val int;
BEGIN
   UPDATE GTAB03 SET lastno=lastno+1 where vrid=ivrid and acyrid=iacyrid and BranchID=ibranchid RETURNING lastno into id_val;

return id_val;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

- the above function is for updating a table 
  the error am getting is follows

> error Parameter name is missing.

Comment: I think you have not declare lastno for lastno+1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created an input parameter and try to use it as an output parameter. The parameter isn't used at all in the query so it couldn't get a value, and the result that is actually returned from the query is ignored.

Remove the parameter, and get the result from the `ExecuteScalar` method:

```
updateGtab03 = command.ExecuteScalar()
```

You should however consider using parameters for the three input values, instead of concatenating them into the query.

Comment: `updateGtab03 = (int)command.ExecuteScalar()` showed an error but `updateGtab03 = command.ExecuteScalar` worked

Comment: @hector: Silly me, I mixed in some C# there... In C# there is no option to turn strict off, so it always needs a cast there. If you compile VB in strict mode, you would need a `Cast` or `DirectCast` to unbox the integer.